# What is the C# equivalent to Java's 0b prefix for Integer literals?

Tags: java, c#, binary, integer, int

I was just wondering this because I'm trying to store binary data in integers in C# like you can in Java by using the "0b" prefix.

Comment: Was [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx) really so hard to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `0x` is `0x`:

```
  int sample = 0xABCD;
```

As for binary, there's *no equivalent*, but you can do *conversion*:

```
  int sample = Convert.ToInt32("1010", 2);
```

However, *C# 6.0* probably will have `0b` prefix feature:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx

Comment: C# 6 won't have it - https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14 (this link is an up-to-date feature list).